# Removing address column and adding labels with objdump assembly

Tags: linux, disassembly

I am using `objdump` disassembly like this:

````sh
objdump -Mintel -ldSrwC --no-show-raw-insn --insn-width=5 --visualize-jumps=extended-color $@```
````

Which gives me this:

```
    3fc8:         sub    rsp,0x8
    3fcc:         call   1000 <_init>
    3fd1:         sar    rbp,0x3
    3fd5:   /----- je     3ff6 <__libc_csu_init+0x56>
    3fd7:   |      xor    ebx,ebx
    3fd9:   |      nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
    3fe0:   |  /-> mov    rdx,r14
    3fe3:   |  |   mov    rsi,r13
    3fe6:   |  |   mov    edi,r12d
    3fe9:   |  |   call   QWORD PTR [r15+rbx*8]
    3fed:   |  |   add    rbx,0x1
    3ff1:   |  |   cmp    rbp,rbx
    3ff4:   |  \-- jne    3fe0 <__libc_csu_init+0x40>
    3ff6:   \----> add    rsp,0x8
    3ffa:         pop    rbx
    3ffb:         pop    rbp
```

Almost perfect, but I

1. do not want the address column
2. I want labels

How do I achieve this using `objdump`? Or do I have to use another program?

Comment: What labels are you referring to? Functions should already be labeled. Short jump labels are not included in runtime code.

Comment: `llvm-objdump` does support the `--no-leading-addr` option (see the [docs](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-objdump.html#cmdoption-llvm-objdump-no-leading-addr)), but it doesn't seem to support all the other goodies that you showed.